# Reopen buffer in split view

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

Is there an built-in option in emacs to toggle between full window and a split window, so that both files remain the same? As if minimizing one buffer for a while. Currently, when I do C-x 3 to split vertically it will open the same buffer, I then open a file in the other window. But at some point I want to concentrate fully on one part again and "minimize" the other half of the window. And later I want to unminimize and have both files shown again. Is this toggling of emacs windows possible?

NB: I use term "window" in emacsian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using `winner-mode' for this purpose:

```
(winner-mode)
(global-set-key [f9] 'delete-other-windows)
(global-set-key [C-f9] 'delete-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'winner-undo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f7>") 'winner-redo)
```

This way

- <kbd>f9</kbd> "maximizes" the current window,
- <kbd>f7</kbd> restores the previous configuration.
- <kbd>C-f9</kbd> "minimizes" the current window.

I rarely use <kbd>C-f7</kbd>, just included it for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [window configuration registers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Configuration-Registers.html#Configuration-Registers) for this.

Answer (score 2):

@Seanmcl's answer is a good one, as is @abo-abo's.

Depending on how you work or just what you want to do, you can also use `C-x 5 2` to open the current buffer in a new frame.  And then use `C-x 5 0` there to delete that frame when done focusing on that buffer.